# $(a_n)$ is bounded $\implies \sum a_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that if $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence, then

$$\sum \frac{1}{n^2} a_n $$ converges

I only could prove that this sequence is bounded, but not its convergence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that if $\sum|b_n|$ is convergent, then so is $\sum b_n$? Because $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}a_n$, then $|b_n|<C\frac1{n^2}$ for some constant $C$....

Comment: Comparison test with $b_n=M/n^2$?

Comment: Thank you, I know this test

Answer (score 10):

Given that $|a_n|\le M$, then we can use the [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) to show that because
$$
\left|\,\frac{a_n}{n^2}\,\right|\le\frac M{n^2}
$$
and that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges, we also have that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^2}$ [converges absolutely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence).

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove convergence it is sufficient to show that the sequence $\{S_M\}_{M\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ given by:
$$ S_M = \sum_{n=1}^{M}\frac{a_n}{n^2}$$
is a Cauchy sequence. Since, assuming $M_1<M_2$:
$$ S_{M_2}-S_{M_1} = \sum_{n=M_1+1}^{M_2}\frac{a_n}{n^2} $$
is bounded in absolute value by:
$$ \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*} |a_n|\cdot\sum_{n=M_1+1}^{M_2}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*} |a_n|\cdot\int_{M_1}^{M_2}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*} |a_n|\cdot\left(\frac{1}{M_1}-\frac{1}{M_2}\right)$$
convergence follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$V \le a_k \le U\tag{k > 0}$$
$$\frac{1}{k^2}V \le \frac{1}{k^2}a_k \le \frac{1}{k^2}U$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}V \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}a_k \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}U$$

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}V \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}a_k \le \frac{\pi^2}{6}U$$

Answer (score 0):

One more way: Dirichlet test, which uses summation by parts. You have $0<a_n <M$ and $\frac{1}{n^2} \to_n 0$, so conditions are satisfied, and the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dirichlet's test, which says: If the partial sum of the series summation (a_n) is bounded and the sequence (b_n) is a monotone sequence converging to zero, then the series summation (a_n b_n) is convergent.

Here (1/n^2) is a monotone sequence converging to zero.

Hint: 0< (1/n^2) < (1/n) and apply squeeze theorem to get the limit.

Comment: Also, if (a_n) was given to be a monotone sequence in addition to being bounded, you could have used Abel's test to prove the result.